# Restricting info to SYS users - Oracle

Tags: security, oracle-12c

Is it possible to restrict sensitive information from users having sysdba role? Does Data redaction help us in achieving this?

I know we can restrict particular schemas to prevent from viewing from sensitive info by using redaction.. but what about sys user? Can that user still view everything?

Comment: The DBA is equivalent to the root user or Administrator, and any user with SYSDBA privileges can do anything.  If you consider this a risk, then your options are limited to Database Vault, or trust your DBAs.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Database Vault was designed for that exact purpose.

Documentation link [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DVADM/dvintro.htm#DVADM70105).

Comment: Yes, vault would be able to do that.. question is will redaction be able to do that?

Comment: @tesla747 - No.  You would either need to use Database Vault or you would need to have the application encrypt the data using a key that is not available to the database or to the DBA.